# jquery onchange not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net, forms

I'm trying to automate web form completion using visual basic. The data fields populate fine, except for one, which remains hidden. When data is put in the qualification field (which is a drop-down menu select), it is not recognized by the website as a "change," so the jquery function: "this.form.submit()" does not happen. If the person is qualified, then a hidden expiration date data field should appear.

Is there a way to trigger this "onchange" or "change" function using my VB code so the necessary data fields appear and form completion can proceed? Here's the code:

VB code to transfer data to web fields

```
  Select Case Me.SubForm_D_P.Form.Qual.Value
    Case "Qualified"
        Me.Browser.Document.getElementById("ResultMenu:Result").focus
        Me.Browser.Document.getElementById("ResultMenu:Result").Value = 2  
        'Call Delay(200)
    Case "Unqualified"
        Me.Browser.Document.getElementById("ResultMenu:Result").focus
        Me.Browser.Document.getElementById("ResultMenu:Result").Value = 0 
    Case "Temporarily DQ"
        Me.Browser.Document.getElementById("ResultMenu:Result").focus
        Me.Browser.Document.getElementById("ResultMenu:Result").Value = 1 
   End Select
```

jquery web code: onchange=this.form.submit();

Comment: can you clarify your exact question?If i understand correctly that you want to submit form on data change?

Comment: Yes, I need to trigger the function: submit() after the data is entered by my process. Somehow the website doesn't recognize that as a "change" Doing the process manually, using the dropdown menu on the website to select the option, populates the data field and refreshes the page, leaving the data there and opening an additional data field for the user to input the expiration date.

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible to trigger that jquery function through the VB code.

Comment: I need to better emulate JS events so the website detects filled fields.

Comment: Using VB code, I need to trigger an "onchange" event after data inserted to field, as website doesn't detect the change.